# fopen on url and bytestream

Tags: php, amazon-s3

i have a question about fopen() and base64 comunication.
The scenario is that: i have a service A that must fetch from url a resource (png/jpeg or pdf). The code is that:

```
    $uri = urldecode($_POST['uri']);
    $imgfile = $uri;
    $handle  = fopen($uri, 'r'); 
    $imagebinary = '';

    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $c = fgetc($handle);
        if($c === false) break;
        $imagebinary .= $c;
    }
    fclose($handle);
    $return =  base64_encode($imagebinary);
```

Now i have JQUERY function that send this $return (something like that: 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAIAAAACDbGyAAAAAXNSR0IArs') to another PHP service, named B.
B service take this string and try to save it on disk. In the specific the service B try to save the file on amazon s3, the code is that:

```
    // in $imagedata is saved the string generated by service A
    $imagedata = $_POST['serviceA_base64encodedfile'];
    // $contentType taken from switch function on $ext
    // for example 'image/png'
    $filename = sha1(uniqid()) . '.' . $ext;
    $full_filename = $path . '/' . $filename;

    $stream = fopen('data://' . $contentType . ';base64,' . $imagedata, 'r');
    fseek($stream, 0);

    $opt = array(
        'fileUpload' => $stream,
        'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC,
        'contentType' => $contentType
    );

    $s3 = new AmazonS3(AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY);
    $response = $s3->create_object($bucket, $filename, $opt);
```

But the image that being saved is corrupted, in additionals this images or pdf have less bytes  then orginal.

I need realy help :D

Comment: You could do `$imageninary = file_get_contents($uri);` instead of doing old-school file operations. This would be more readable and may (or may not) solve your problem.

Comment: thanks, i change all my fopen, but this is not the way.. any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this will work, but why not base64_decode the data back to binary, then write the data to a temporary file and send it to amazon from that location. Something like (untested):

```
// in $imagedata is saved the string generated by service A
    $imagedata = base64_decode($_POST['serviceA_base64encodedfile']);
    if (!$imagedata){
        //Handle invalid base64 encoded data
    }
    // $contentType taken from switch function on $ext
    // for example 'image/png'
    $filename = sha1(uniqid()) . '.' . $ext;
    $full_filename = $path . '/' . $filename;

    $tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "image_to_upload");
    $populated =  file_put_contents($tmpfname,$imagedata);
    if (!$populated){
        //handle write failures 
    }

    $opt = array(
        'fileUpload'    => "/tmp/".$tmpfname,
        'acl'           => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC,
        'contentType'   => $contentType
    );

    $s3 = new AmazonS3(AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY);
    $response = $s3->create_object($bucket, $full_filename, $opt);
```

I'm also presuming on the last call, that $full_filename is where you want to store the file on the s3 server... though you can just use $file_name.

Comment: The error is caused by HTTP: the base64 string lost all + char when it is sent to Service B. The way is call urlencoded on based64 string, and urldecode before fopen/file_get_contents.

Thanks to all